# How to change Swagger's Json in the ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger-ui

I have an API that is meeting the requisition requirements of the JsonApi Specification. In my swagger the request example is with Json in the format of my entity. Does anyone know a way to change this?

Comment: Sorry Alisson...you need to provide more info

Comment: You want to change the sample JSON that the Swagger UI shows?

Comment: Your question is not clear! more info please.

Comment: Do you meet any error message? Can you post the related Swagger's json and the related API method, so that we could try to reproduce the problem and help you solve the problem.

Comment: @mason I have some APIs that are using the jsonapi.org standard, but swagger cannot identify the examples correctly.

Comment: Basically I want to hange the sample JSON that SwaggerUI shows.